# Spring Boot - проблема с подключением базы данных в веб приложении на Java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Пытаюсь подключить БД к проекту используя Spring Boot, по лекциям на ютубе:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyFLX3q3poY

БД PostrgeSQL, application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sweater
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Код приложения:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
@Autowired
private MessageRepo messageRepo;
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name,
                       Map<String, Object> model) {
    log.debug("greeting ");

    model.put("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}
@GetMapping
public String main(Map<String, Object> model){
    log.debug("main ");
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}

@PostMapping
public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model){
    Message message = new Message();
    messageRepo.save(message);
     Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
     model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}

@Entity
public class Message {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String text;

private String tag;

public Message() {
}

public Message(String text, String tag) {
    this.text = text;
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}
```

а это веб:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="введите сообщение"/>
      <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Тэг"/>
      <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div> список сообщений </div>
    {{#messages}}
    <div>
      <b>{{id}}</b>
      <span>{{text}}</span>
      <i>{{tag}}</i>
    </div>
    {{/messages}}
</body>
</html>
```

Запускаю приложение, открываю веб форму, ввожу данные и нажимаю кнопку add и вылетает ошибка: 
Whitelabel Error Page, 
а в отладчике:

2020-04-18 17:32:15.462 ERROR 7564 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No key, method or field with name 'text' on line 14] with root cause
com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No key, method or field with name 'text' on line 14

БД sweater создана, таблица messages тоже.
В чем проблема?

Comment: А какой url вводишь в браузере?

Comment: вот так: localhost:8080

Comment: Пробовал дебажить? Поставь breakpoint'ы в метод main и посмотри что внутри твоих messages

Comment: на main все ок - читает  две записи из БД и записывает их в мапу
а вот при выходе из main где-то в дебрях spring вылетает ошибка, причем сейчас она уже даже веб форму не отображает

Comment: Слетела таблица, заново создал ее. Дошел до добавления. Что-то тут в методе add не так, в message все в null, кроме id. А поля text и tag ни чему не присваиваются. Скорее всего Поэтому и ошибка

Answer (score 0):

ошибка была в создании объекта, надо было вызывать такой конструктор:

```
new Message(text, tag);
```